# Programmatically set form's fields keeps the form invalid

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

In a Ionic 3 / Angular 5 app I have a form composed of 3 fields:

- firstname (input text)
- birthdate (datetime picker)
- avatar (radio button)

The submit button is disabled if the form is invalid:
`[disabled]="!addChildForm.valid"`

At init time I check if the user is creating a new child or editing one. I editing, I programmatically populates the fields.
This works fine but the submit button is inactive. Though the birthdate is well populated I must click it to open (and close) the picker to enable the submit button.

My code:

```
createForm(child?: Child): void {

      this.addChildForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstnameInput: ['', Validators.required],
        birthdateInput: ['', Validators.required],
        avatarInput: ['', Validators.required]
      });

      // If we are editing a child, populate the form
      if (child) {
        this.addChildForm.setValue({
          firstnameInput: child.firstname,
          birthdateInput: moment(child.birthdate).format(),
          avatarInput: child.avatar
        });
      }
    }
```

Any idea how I could somehow force the form to make a check round to enable the submit button after populating the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building the form and *then* populating it with data, do your checks in the build step and complete it in one pass. Like this:

```
createForm(child?: Child): void {

  this.addChildForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstnameInput: [child ? child.firstname : '', Validators.required],
    birthdateInput: [child ? moment(child.birthdate).format() : '', Validators.required],
    avatarInput: [child ? child.avatar : '', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

Here is a link with a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygaoz7.

Try changing the initial values of `this.child` in the example to empty strings and you will see the form change and the submit button become disabled. When they all have values, the button is enabled again.

Comment: Then it may be an issue with your data -- are the properties `firstname`, `birthdate`, and `avatar` *always* defined / have values on `Child`?

Comment: Yes I see them being filled in the form.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a plunkr or stackblitz?

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain a link with a working example.

Comment: I had a conflict between `formName` and `ngModel`